# "Subatomic physics" terminology

Tags: terminology, definition, subatomic

Unlike the [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/532835/) which was closed very early which presents the context of this question, I am asking about the terminology of "subatomic physics" and NOT about a specific book. I would like to know what is included in this wording and if it is only particle physics?

Comment: _Subatomic_ just means _smaller than an atom._

Comment: @Qmechanic I know that but can you be more specific and exhaustive about what it involves. I did not ask the meaning of the word but the meaning of it as one or multiple subjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subatomic physics includes nuclear physics.  There has been much written about nuclear physics. The subject includes the nucleus and its constituents, the protons and neutrons.  In scattering you must also consider the projectile and its components. All these are subatomic particles. After a collision, the resulting particles, like nucleons, $\beta$-particles, and neutrinos are all subatomic particles as well.

Aside from nuclear physics, there is the subject you mentioned, particle physics. It goes a step deeper by looking at the constituents of the protons and neutrons and many other subatomic particles.

Comment: Is QFT included? Is chromodynamics included? @jmh

Comment: If you got deep into theoretical nuclear physics you would need to use quantum chromodynamics.  I suppose QFT would be used - I'm not a theoretical nuclear physicist so I don't really know.